# How can i add new field into drf query output?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

there is get query  in Drf get_object

```
query_get = get_object_or_404(My_model, id=1)
```

i want to add new field in this out put.but do not work.
when i use

```
 query_get['new_field']='1'
```

then return that,but can not add new_field in out put.

Comment: Have you tried `query_get.new_field = "1"`?

Comment: yes..it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a serializer, you can use it by adding methodfield as follows.

```
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    new_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_new_field(obj):
        return "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

get_object_or_404() returns an object, not a queryset. So in your case it will return an instance of My_model with an id of 1.

The way to pass an extra field to the template depends on whether you're using a class-based or function based view.

In case of function-based view:

```
query_get = get_object_or_404(My_model, id=1)
context['query_get'] = query_get
context['new_field'] = '1'
return render(request, "my_template.html", context)
```

With a class based view you can override the get_context_data() method:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        # Add data to the context
        query_get = get_object_or_404(My_model, id=1)
        context['query_get'] = query_get
        context['new_field'] = '1'
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks ..but i forgot to say this  problem is in drf django